# Lambert Omega Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just solved a problem and I reached a point where I could no longer simplify the equation. Being as impatient as I usually am on a Friday, I plugged my final line of derivation into WolframAlpha and out came a function I did not expect to see.

Here is the problem and my derivation:

> Find the general solution to the differential equation $$x^2y'+y^2 = xyy'$$
>
> **Solution**: First, rewrite the equation using infinitesimals
>   \begin{align*}x^2dy+y^2dx &= xydy\\
> \end{align*}
>   Let $y=vx$, and hence $dy = xdv + vdx$
>   \begin{align*}x^2 (xdv + vdx)+v^2 x^2dx &= vx^2(xdv + vdx)\\
> x^3dv + (x^2v+v^2 x^2)dx &= vx^3dv + v^2x^2dx\\
> x^2v dx &= x^3(v - 1)dv\\
> \dfrac{1}{x} dx &= (1 - \dfrac{1}{v})dv\\
> \ln(x) &= v - \ln(v) + C\\
> \ln\biggr(\dfrac{y}{v}\biggr) &= v - \ln(v) + C\\
> \ln(y) - \ln(v)&= v - \ln(v) + C\\
> \ln(y) &= v + C\\
> y = Ce^v\\
> y = Ce^{y/x}\\
> \end{align*}

At this point I did not know what to do. So I plugged in that last line to WolframAlpha and out came
$$y=-x W(-C/x)$$
where $W$ is the Lambert $W$-Function. I read Mathworld's page about this function and I understand its definition, but I can't seem to derive the same result on my own. Would anyone mind showing me how to get from my last line ($y = Ce^{y/x}$) to the closed form containing the Lambert $W$-Function?

Comment: $$y=Ce^{y/x}\iff (-y/x)e^{-y/x}=-C/x\iff -y/x=W(-C/x)$$ (When in doubt, work backwards.)

Comment: Click on the button Step-by-step solution.

Comment: Lol, you think I didn't try that? "step-by-step solution unavailable"

Comment: Sorry :-) Some minutes ago WA offered 3 times free per day or Pro. Never mind. Maybe you (or we) can ask @anon to migrate your comment to answer.

Comment: No you don't understand: WA will still give step-by-step solutions, just *not for this particular problem*.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the answer here is *really* close, just hidden a little. Taking your last equation
$$
y=Ce^{y/x}
$$
divide by $e^{y/x}$, or essentially multiply by $e^{-y/x}$ and you get
$$
ye^{-y/x}=C
$$
This is the tricky part. Since we only care about getting $y$ alone, we can divide by $-x$ on both sides, setting up
$$
\frac{y}{-x}e^{(-y/x)}=\frac{C}{-x}
$$
Here, we have this in the form of $f(u) = ue^u$ where $u=\frac{-y}{x}$ and we can take the $W$ of both sides:
$$
W\left(\frac{-y}{x}e^{\frac{-y}{x}}\right)=W\left(\frac{-C}{x}\right)
$$
$$
\frac{-y}{x}=W\left(\frac{-C}{x}\right)
$$
$$
y=-xW\left(\frac{-C}{x}\right)
$$